# Inserting variables into a regular expression string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found a lot questions on StackOverflow about how to do this, but it's just not working for me.

```
var username = "abcdefg";
var min_length = 3;
var max_length = 24;
var regex = new RegExp('^[\w.-]{' + min_length + ',' + max_length + '}$');
if (regex.test(username))
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'match';
else
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'no match';
```

I've also tried with slashes before and after:

```
new RegExp('/^[\w.-]{' + min_length + ',' + max_length + '}$/')
```

And I've also tried with double quotes instead of single quotes (not sure if regex treats single quotes as reserved or something).

If I remove the quotes and put in numbers for the variables it works fine:

```
new RegExp(/^[\w.-]{3,24}$/)
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/88ef3/

Comment: And you're sure that works if you just type the numbers instead ?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/88ef3/1/

Comment: you are including `/` in your pattern in the jsfiddle

Comment: yes, but I've tried it with and without

Comment: look here http://jsfiddle.net/Yp4sp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `RegExp` constructor to build a regular expression from a string, you must escape slashes:

```
new RegExp('^[\\w.-]{' + min_length + ',' + max_length + '}$');
```

Remember that a slash in a javascript string is used to escape, but here you want the slah as a character, so you must escape itself.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/88ef3/3/)

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I'll accept this after the 10 minute period is up.

Comment: @Gavin also note from other comments that you do not use `/` in `RegExp` constructor, because the `/` is the delimiter for regex literals.

Comment: That's what I figured, I just couldn't figure out why this wasn't working so I tried everything I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

```
new RegExp('^[\\w.-]{' + min_length + ',' + max_length + '}$')
```

Comment: Thanks, but Oriol beat you to it :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
var username = "abcdefg";
var min_length = 3;
var max_length = 24;
var str1='^[\\w.-]{'+min_length+','+max_length+'}$';
var regex = new RegExp(str1,"i");
if (regex.test(username))
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'match';
else
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'no match';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Et7J8/